# Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "ControllerContext"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**MVC 6**.

> Ошибка CS0246  Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "ControllerContext" (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку).

```
public class CartModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private const string sessionKey = "Cart";

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Получить объект Cart из сеанса
        Cart cart = null;
        if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
        {
            cart = (Cart)controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey];
        }

        // Создать объект Cart если он не обнаружен в сеансе
        if (cart == null)
        {
            cart = new Cart();
            if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Session != null)
            {
                controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionKey] = cart;
            }
        }

        // Возвратить объект Cart
        return cart;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь пересадить код из ASP.NET 4 в ASP.NET 5 (MVC5 -> MVC6). Это да разных фреймворка, и ASP.NET 5 / MVC 6 еще не в релизе. Может быть вам стоит начать осваивать MVC на стабильной версии?

Comment: И в целом - ModelBinders-ы предназначены для преобразования данных из запроса в модель. Кода, который достает корзину из сессии, в них быть не должно. Это просто использование механизма binder-ов для чего-то совершенно левого, что обязательно вызовет у вас проблемы.